# Inserting text at a specific line in a file using C++

Tags: c++

I am wondering if there is a way of inserting text in a text file at a specific line.

For example:
myfile.txt

```
1 aaaaaaas
2 sflke sdfsd els 
3 sdfsd sdfks ee
4
5 sdflksdfe slkfe
```

I would like to find that line 4 and insert the text bbbb

Comment: Read the file into memory (probably into a `std::vector<std::string>`), modify the line, write the data out to the file.

Comment: You can't insert things at arbitrary locations in a file of any kind, you can only add things at the end.

Comment: @molbdnilo: A file is like an `std::vector`, it can grow dynamically.  To insert, you have to grow the file, then move everything "down", then insert.  But inserting can be performed.  You can also insert by overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the lines into a `vector<string>` and modify that vector, then recreate the file:

```
//string to hold each line for insert into vector
string fileLine;
//vector to hold all lines
vector<string> lines;

//open file for reading
ifstream readFile("filepath.txt");
if (readFile.is_open())
{
    //read lines and push into vector
    while (getline(readFile, fileLine))
    {
        lines.push_back(fileLine);
    }
}

//adjust line 4 of vector
lines[3] = "bbbb";

//open file for writing, use ofstream::trunc to erase file and replace with vector
ofstream newFile("filepath.txt", ofstream::trunc);

//iterate vector and add lines
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    newFile << lines[i] << endl;
}

//close file
newFile.close();
```